# Is it safe to use a blower to clean debris off a shingle roof?

Tags: roof, cleaning, blower

I would like to routinely (once a month) clean the debris (leaves, sticks, pollen, etc.) that collects on my shingle roof because of the shallow pitch:
[image: shallow pitch shingle roof]

Rather than use a soft broom to brush the debris off, it would be less work to use a leaf blower.  Is it safe to do so, or will a leaf blower be too powerful and damage the shingles?

Comment: If you start from the Rige or top and work down a blower would be much better for the roof.

Comment: Yep, don't lift the shingles when you use it, which as @EdBeal notes, blow down-slope and also keep the nozzle up away from the roofing so you don't develop aerodynamic lift. While the tar strips should prevent this lifting, every so often they fail if the airflow is right.